# htaccess redirect wordpress to index2.php

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, .htaccess, tracking

We have a site running on WordPress ada.localhost.com

Now all request to base url (http://ada.localhost.com/) have to go through tracking page (track.com/c/0912321323/?u=xxx) where u parameter is where to redirect user after he is tracked.

I've created a copy of index.php (index2.php) and I want to create htaccess rule to redirect all base url traffic to:

http://track.com/c/0912321323?u=http%3A%2F%2Fada.localhost.com%2Findex2.html (http://ada.localhost.com/index2.php)

Typical WP htaccess file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any clue on how to set it up and if WordPress allow this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

From what I found WordPress won't work with index2.php. 
Solution for this is to write a plugin which deals with it.

Comment: +1 Yes I was going to write this in comment section below your question :)